# Why TextField does not use its lineLimit to go to next line?

Tags: swiftui

I have a TextField which has lineLimit of 10. When the length of the text of TextField gets bigger than its frame, instead of using next line, it continues typing in the same line as before. Why does TextField not use its lineLimit?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var stringOfText: String = "Hello, world!"
    
    var body: some View {

        TextField("", text: $stringOfText)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 200, alignment: .top)
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .lineLimit(10)

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lineLimit` is a modifier (more specifically, it adds an environment attribute) for `Text`, not `TextField`. From the SwiftUI headers on `lineLimit`:

> The line limit applies to all `Text` instances within a hierarchy.

`TextField` is for single-line input. SwiftUI 2.0 introduced `TextEditor` for multiline input, which will wrap by default.

From the TextEditor documentation:

> If you want to change the spacing or font scaling aspects of the text, you can use modifiers like lineLimit(*:), lineSpacing(*:), and minimumScaleFactor(*:) to configure how the view displays text depending on the space constraints. For example, here the lineSpacing(*:) modifier sets the spacing between lines to 5 points:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/texteditor

Comment: TextEditor is in the fact UITextView, do you think is it so hard or difficult to apple to make SwiftUI version of it?

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t understand the question. If you mean why isn’t it a “pure” SwiftUI representation, my answer would be that very few SwiftUI elements are. Many are wrapped versions of their UIKit, AppKit counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: Not sure if I understood the question right, but think the answer could be relative/useful.*

Think you need to specify `axis: .vertical` to parameters of TextField initializer:

```
TextField("Type here...", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
```

So the example code can look like so:

```
struct YourTextView: View {
    @Binding var text: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            TextField("Your plaholder here...", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
                .frame(minHeight: 18)
                .lineLimit(10)
                .padding(.vertical, 12)
                .padding(.horizontal, 16)
        }
        .background(Color.accentColor)
    }
}

#Preview {
    YourTextView(
        text: .constant("Vitae fringilla suspendisse amet in sodales. Morbi tincidunt tellus lacinia purus. Id eleifend porta tincidunt viverra cras fringilla neque aliquam. Porta tincidunt id elit tincidunt ac donec etiam ultrices. Egestas faucibus nunc eleifend elit imperdiet facilisis ut elementum sed."),
        action: {}
    )
}
```